# Is there anyway to compile mac binaries from a windows machine?

Tags: objective-c, windows, cocoa, macos

Seems like there wouldn't be, but it would help us out if there was. I wish to pull the source down to a windows server and compile it and have it be the same as if I had pulled the source code down to a mac machine and used xcode on it. Any Ideas?

Reasons: Release Engineering and IT are much more familiar and comfortable on windows, so it would be easier on us, and LaunchD sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Your original question had less detail... I think you are creating more problems than you are solving buy not using a Mac. Is it really that hard to learn to compile under Xcode or type make in the console?

Anyway...

Apple uses a modified version of the GCC C/C++/Objective C compiler with a proprietary runtime library... You could develop using a port of this code to Windows. See GNUStep.Org. This is not binary compatible though but it isn't impossible that you could rebuild it to cross compile to something that was Mac OS X compatible.

Another idea would be to develop using c# .NET and then move the binaries across to Mac OS X and run the binaries using Mono....

None of these options are robust enough to allow you to do this blind without a Macintosh to test and get up and running in the first place.

Comment: this would not be for the developer machines, they are more than happy on thier macs. It is more for the continuous integration, and build server maintenance. Also, it is a pain for those of us that have to learn two different servers (Windows and Mac)

Comment: Well we are only looking for options, currently all build servers are Mac and run xcode. It is just these servers suck so bad, we spend more time baby sitting 2 mac servers then dozens of windows servers. Plus it would be nice, since we are a Win and Mac shop, to keep one continuous integration syste, 1 reporting system, 1 source control system, and everything else. The fact is we just don't want two systems so I thought I hope for a miracle.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile cross app with [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) but only on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need launchd? cron works just as well on Mac as it does on Linux, just have a cronjob that does (Extremely simplified version ahead):

```
cd /my/source/dir
git pull  # You are using Git, right?
xcodebuild MyCoolProject.xcodeproj
cp -r build/MyApp.app /the/distribution/folder
```