# Do I need to buy a Mac, to compile my Python extensions written in Rust for Mac OS?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3, maturin

My development environment is configured in Windows. I could compile for Linux using WSL. Is there anyway possible, so that I can compile for Mac OS without having to buy a Mac?

I have no idea how to do this any other way.

For context: I am using PyO3 bindings.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319300

Comment: If you are using `pyo3`, you probably want to [read the fine manual](https://pyo3.rs/main/building_and_distribution#cross-compiling)

Comment: https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross

Comment: You can use a MacOS [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance. It will cost money while running, so shut it down when you are done compiling the extensions. The most fun way would be to buy a Mac, however.

Answer (score -3):

Python is cross platform and you can easily build pure python packages that run on mac. More generally, lots of compilers will cross-compile to multiple platform so you can build on one type and run on another. And many platforms have virtual machines that run under windows. Run the virtual machine and you could use mac tools natively. As long as you aren't writing hardware dependent code, you likely don't need a mac to write for mac.

Comment: The fact that the OP is using pyoxide -- and that part of their code is written in Rust rather than pure Python -- tells us that their code _is_ hardware-dependent.

Comment: (Another complicating factor is that Apple's binary "notarization" mechanism historically was not always possible to run without using their own closed-source tooling; I don't know whether and to what extent that's still true, or to what extent it applies to the use case at hand).